# Meteor.js MYSQL output to template

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, templates, meteor

I am new to node and meteor.js.  I am trying to wrap my head around some of the basic functionality coming from PHP/MYSQL.

I am trying to work with the node npm MYSQL to output a list of data to a template file, but can't seem to get the data to connect to the template.  I can get the data to output to console.log - but not to the template.

Here is my server connection.

```
var eventName = [];
if (Meteor.isServer) {

Meteor.methods({
 'geteventName': function () {
  this.unblock();
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  socketPath  : '...socketpath',
  database : 'database'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT eventName FROM events', function(err, rows, fields) {
if (err) throw err;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  eventName.push(rows[i]);
};
//console.log(eventName);
return eventName;

});
connection.end();
//return "some return value";

}
});
}


if (Meteor.isClient) {
Meteor.call('geteventName', function (error, result) {
console.log(result);
});
}
```

** I have updated the code based on the comments, but the Meteor call just returns undefined.  If I set a general variable to return - i.e. I just had it set to some dummy text, the results passes through to the client and returns in the console.

Comment: Your schoolName var is not available on the client, you should put it outside of Meteor.isServer/isClient blocks.
Also, #each is for collections not variables.

Comment: Hi Bennyz - thanks for the comment and suggestion, but in all honesty I don't know enough about the framework to connect what you are saying to your recommendation.  I understand that it should be outside the .isServer method, but how/where should it go?  I split my folders and files up to a server and client file.  I put the variable declaration in a client.js file, but then I get a meteor error and the application crashes.  If I keep it in the server method I get the data I want returned to the console.

Comment: The lib directory is available to both client and server.
But you should probably create a method on the server with Meteor.methods({}) and then use Meteor.call() on the client to retrieve the results

Comment: Hi Bennyz, I've spent some more time looking at Meteor examples and tutorials.  I can finally get the server method function to pass some text, if the variable is set - but I can not get the function to return a JSON object back to the client.  If I run console.log on the server I can see the whole object constructed, but if I run the same on the meteor.call function return all I get is undefined.  I have updated my code above to show the changes.